# How to fix "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3656: ordinal not in range(128)" error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I am writing a code to crawl a student timetable from the school website using Beautifulsoup. The issue is I keep having this UnicodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3656: ordinal not in range(128) result and I cannot resolve it.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

timetabledatasaved = ""
soup = make_soup("http://timetable.ait.ie/reporting/textspreadsheet;student+set;id;AL%5FKSWFT%5FR%5F5%0D%0A?t"
             "=student+set+textspreadsheet&days=1-5&weeks=21-32&periods="
             "3-20&template=student+set+textspreadsheet")

for record in soup.find_all('tr'):
    timetabledata = ""
    print record
    print '--------------------'
    for data in record('td'):
        timetabledata = timetabledata + "," + data.text
    if len(timetabledata) != 0:
        timetabledatasaved = timetabledatasaved + "\n" + timetabledata[1:]

#print timetabledatasaved

header = "Activity, Module, Type, Start, End, Duration, Weeks, Room, Staff, Student Groups"
file = open(os.path.expanduser("timetable.csv"), "wb")
file.write(bytes(header).encode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(timetabledatasaved).encode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
```

I used Utf-8 but it still gives me this error after crawling the timetable. Again, I realized that my code seems to crawl even the javascripts in the page but I only want it to print out the relevant timetable data and save it as a .csv file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tobenna/PycharmProjects/final_project/venv/timetable_scrape.py", line 30, in <module>
    file.write(bytes(timetabledatasaved).encode("utf-8", errors="ignore")) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3656: ordinal not in range(128)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytes` in Python 2 is a synonym for `str`, so by calling `bytes()` on your values you're encoding them as ASCII, which can't handle characters like `'\xa0'`.  Encode the values directly:

```
file.write(header.encode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
file.write(timetabledatasaved.encode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
```